# How do I create an object that implements an interface?

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I want to create an object that implements an interface and t hen return a reference to it. I've seen how to test whether the object implements an interface but I'm not sure how to do it in the first place.

The interface is as follows:

```
public interface IInformation 
{
    string name { get; set; }
    string description { get; }
    string age { get; set; }
}
```

And this is where I am trying to create the object, in a new class:

```
public IInformation NewInformation(string description)
{
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need a `class Information: IInformation{}` first.

Comment: Try reading a bit about interfaces. E.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To implement a interface you need to create a class say 'myClass' in my example and use the ':' symbol followed by the interface name. then right click the interface and press the button 'implement interface' this will auto generate all of the methods of your interface but you need to make sure that you change the default implementation from

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

to whatever logic you wish to use.

```
   public interface IInformation
        {
            string name { get; set; }
            string description { get; }
            string age { get; set; }
        }

        public class myClass : IInformation
        {
            public string age
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public string description
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public string name
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then to use the class you will need to do something like this:

```
public IInformation NewInformation(string description)
{
    myClass myInstance = new myClass();
    myInstance.description = description;
    return myInstance;
}
```